# I need help with two select statements using join

Tags: sql, join

Here are the two statements I want in one:

```
SELECT pictures.picture, users.fname, users.lname, users.email, users.phone
FROM users, pictures
WHERE users.userid = 1
AND pictures.userid = users.userid;
```

and

```
SELECT pictures.picture, users.fname, users.lname, posts.post, 'post' AS 
type
FROM users, posts, pictures
WHERE users.userid = posts.userid
AND posts.postid > 0
AND users.userid =1
AND pictures.userid = users.userid
GROUP BY time
```

Previously I've been using a UNION statement but I can't do that in this case since the amount of columns in the two statements don't match.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is an extremely poor practice to use implied joins. PLease learn how to write explicit joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.picture, u.fname, u.lname, u.email, u.phone, p.post, 'post' AS type
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN posts p ON u.userid = p.userid
LEFT JOIN pictures pic ON pic.user_id = u.userid
WHERE u.userid = 1
GROUP BY time
```

You may change the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` if you require posts or pictures in the result set.

Comment: How do I do if I want the email, phone number, first name, second name and picture to appear at the top and then the posts underneath? The posts may include first name and picture aswell.

Comment: You arent going to get that kind of response from your RDBMS directly. You can use an ORM to get that kind of grouping (parent/child) or do it manually. To do this, order your results by user and then only display the user details the first time you see that user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UNION if you make your column lists match up.  For example:

```
SELECT pictures.picture, users.fname, users.lname, users.email, users.phone, NULL, NULL
FROM users, pictures
WHERE users.userid = 1
AND pictures.userid = users.userid
UNION ALL
SELECT pictures.picture, users.fname, users.lname, NULL, NULL, posts.post, 'post' AS 
type
FROM users, posts, pictures
WHERE users.userid = posts.userid
AND posts.postid > 0
AND users.userid =1
AND pictures.userid = users.userid
GROUP BY time
```

Comment: I get an error when trying this: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION ALL
SELECT pictures.picture, users.fname, users.lname, NULL, NULL, posts.' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT pictures.picture, users.fname, users.lname, posts.post, 
       'post' AS type, users.email, users.phone
FROM users 
INNER JOIN pictures ON users.userid = pictures.userid
INNER JOIN posts on users.userid = posts.userid
WHERE users.userid = 1
AND posts.postid > 0
GROUP BY time;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a dumb question and I may not be understanding something, but why do you need two statements?

```
SELECT pictures.picture, users.fname, users.lname, 
FROM users, pictures
WHERE users.userid = 1
AND pictures.userid = users.userid;

SELECT pictures.picture, users.fname, users.lname, posts.post, 
    'post' AS type, users.email, users.phone
FROM users
LEFT JOIN posts ON (posts.userid = users.userid AND posts.postid > 0)
LEFT JOIN pictures (pictures.userid = users.userid)
WHERE users.userid =1
GROUP BY time
```

Hope that helps.